# Golang Mocking with Elastic

Tags: unit-testing, go

I've built a quick and easy API in Go that queries ElasticSearch. Now that I know it can be done, I want to do it correctly by adding tests. I've abstracted some of my code so that it can be unit-testable, but I've been having some issues mocking the elastic library, and as such I figured it would be best if I tried a simple case to mock just that.

```
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "github.com/olivere/elastic"
    "net/http"
)
...
func CheckBucketExists(name string, client *elastic.Client) bool {
    exists, err := client.IndexExists(name).Do()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return exists
}
```

And now the test...

```
  import (
      "fmt"
      "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
      "github.com/stretchr/testify/mock"
      "testing"
  )

type MockClient struct {
      mock.Mock
  }

  func (m *MockClient) IndexExists(name string) (bool, error) {
      args := m.Mock.Called()
      fmt.Println("This is a thing")
      return args.Bool(0), args.Error(1)
  }

  func TestMockBucketExists(t *testing.T) {
      m := MockClient{}
      m.On("IndexExists", "thisuri").Return(true)

>>    r := CheckBucketExists("thisuri", m)
      assert := assert.New(t)
      assert.True(r, true)
  }
```

To which I'm yielded with the following error: `cannot use m (type MockClient) as type *elastic.Client in argument to CheckBucketExists`.

I'm assuming this is something fundamental with my use of the elastic.client type, but I'm still too much of a noob.

Answer (score 5):

This is an old question, but couldn't find the solution either. 
Unfortunately, this library is implemented using a struct, that makes mocking it not trivial at all, so the options I found are:

(1) Wrap all the `elastic.SearchResult` Methods on an interface on your own and "proxy" the call, so you end up with something like:

```
type ObjectsearchESClient interface {
    // ... all methods... 
    Do(context.Context) (*elastic.SearchResult, error)
}


// NewObjectsearchESClient returns a new implementation of ObjectsearchESClient
func NewObjectsearchESClient(cluster *config.ESCluster) (ObjectsearchESClient, error) {
    esClient, err := newESClient(cluster)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    newClient := objectsearchESClient{
        Client: esClient,
    }
    return &newClient, nil
}
// ... all methods... 
func (oc *objectsearchESClient) Do(ctx context.Context) (*elastic.SearchResult, error) {
    return oc.searchService.Do(ctx)
}
```

And then mock this interface and responses as you would with other modules of your app.

(2) Another option is like pointed in [this blog post](http://goinbigdata.com/unit-testing-golang-code-calling-elasticsearch/) that is mock the response from the Rest calls using `httptest.Server`

for this, I mocked the handler, that consist of mocking the response from the "HTTP call"

```
func mockHandler () http.HandlerFunc{
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        resp := `{
            "took": 73,
            "timed_out": false,
            ... json ... 
            "hits": [... ]
            ...json ... ,
            "aggregations": { ... }
        }`

        w.Write([]byte(resp))
    }
}
```

Then you create a dummy elastic.Client struct

```
func mockClient(url string) (*elastic.Client, error) {
    client, err := elastic.NewSimpleClient(elastic.SetURL(url))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return client, nil
}
```

In this case, I've a library that builds my elastic.SearchService and returns it, so I use the HTTP like:

```
    ... 
    ts := httptest.NewServer(mockHandler())
    defer ts.Close()
    esClient, err := mockClient(ts.URL)
    ss := elastic.NewSearchService(esClient)
    mockLibESClient := es_mock.NewMockSearcherClient(mockCtrl)
    mockLibESClient.EXPECT().GetEmployeeSearchServices(ctx).Return(ss, nil)
```

where mockLibESClient is the library I mentioned, and we stub the `mockLibESClient.GetEmployeeSearchServices` method making it return the SearchService with that will return the expected payload.

Note: for creating the mock mockLibESClient I used https://github.com/golang/mock

I found this to be convoluted, but "Wrapping" the elastic.Client was in my point of view more work.

Question: I tried to mock it by using `https://github.com/vburenin/ifacemaker` to create an interface, and then mock that interface with `https://github.com/golang/mock` and kind of use it, but I kept getting compatibility errors when trying to return an interface instead of a struct, I'm not a Go expect at all so probably I needed to understand the typecasting a little better to be able to solve it like that.  So if any of you know how to do it with that please let me know.

Comment: This was my question initially, and I haven't done much Go since I posted this years ago. [CodeReviewComments#Interfaces](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#interfaces) suggests that the external library should implement the struct, and the user should define an interface on that struct, passing it in using dep injection. Which, points to the first solution you mentioned in your post!

Answer (score 2):

The elasticsearch [go client Github repo](https://github.com/elastic/go-elasticsearch) contains [an official example](https://github.com/elastic/go-elasticsearch/blob/main/_examples/xkcdsearch/store_test.go) of how to mock the elasticsearch client. It basically involves calling `NewClient` with a configuration which stubs the HTTP transport:

```
client, err := elasticsearch.NewClient(elasticsearch.Config{
    Transport: &mocktrans,
})
```

Answer (score 0):

There are primarily three ways I discovered to create a Mock/Dumy ES client. My response does not include integration tests against a real Elasticsearch cluster.

1. You can follow this [article](https://medium.com/@ievstrygul/testing-elasticsearch-app-in-go-b32addb1a8d3) so as to mock the response from the Rest calls using httptest.Server, to eventually create a dummy elastic.Client struct
2. As mentioned by the package author in this [link](https://github.com/olivere/elastic/wiki/Testing), you can work on "specifying an interface that has two implementations: One that uses a real ES cluster, and one that uses callbacks used in testing. Here's an example to get you started:"

```
type Searcher interface {
    Search(context.Context, SearchRequest) (*SearchResponse, error)
}

// ESSearcher will be used with a real ES cluster.
type ESSearcher struct {
    client *elastic.Client
}

func (s *ESSearcher) Search(ctx context.Context, req SearchRequest) (*SearchResponse, error) {
    // Use s.client to run against real ES cluster and perform a search
}

// MockedSearcher can be used in testing.
type MockedSearcher struct {
    OnSearch func(context.Context, SearchRequest) (*SearchResponse, error)
}

func (s *ESSearcher) Search(ctx context.Context, req SearchRequest) (*SearchResponse, error) {
    return s.OnSearch(ctx, req)
}
```

1. Finally, as mentioned by the author in the same [link](https://github.com/olivere/elastic/wiki/Testing) you can "run a real Elasticsearch cluster while testing. One particular nice way might be to start the ES cluster during testing with something like github.com/ory/dockertest. Here's an example to get you started:"

```
package search

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "testing"

    "github.com/olivere/elastic/v7"
    "github.com/ory/dockertest/v3"
    "github.com/ory/dockertest/v3/docker"
)

// client will be initialize in TestMain
var client *elastic.Client

func TestMain(m *testing.M) {
    pool, err := dockertest.NewPool("")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("unable to create new pool: %v", err)
    }

    options := &dockertest.RunOptions{
        Repository: "docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-oss",
        Tag:        "7.8.0",
        PortBindings: map[docker.Port][]docker.PortBinding{
            "9200": {{HostPort: "9200"}},
        },
        Env: []string{
            "cluster.name=elasticsearch",
            "bootstrap.memory_lock=true",
            "discovery.type=single-node",
            "network.publish_host=127.0.0.1",
            "logger.org.elasticsearch=warn",
            "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1g -Xmx1g",
        },
    }
    resource, err := pool.RunWithOptions(options)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("unable to ES: %v", err)
    }
    endpoint := fmt.Sprintf("http://127.0.0.1:%s", resource.GetPort("9200/tcp"))

    if err := pool.Retry(func() error {
        var err error
        client, err = elastic.NewClient(
            elastic.SetURL(endpoint),
            elastic.SetSniff(false),
            elastic.SetHealthcheck(false),
        )
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        _, _, err = client.Ping(endpoint).Do(context.Background())
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        return nil
    }); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("unable to connect to ES: %v", err)
    }

    code := m.Run()

    if err := pool.Purge(resource); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("unable to stop ES: %v", err)
    }

    os.Exit(code)
}

func TestAgainstRealCluster(t *testing.T) {
    // You can use "client" variable here

    // Example code:
    exists, err := client.IndexExists("cities-test").Do(context.Background())
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }
    if !exists {
        t.Fatal("expected to find ES index")
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The line

```
func CheckBucketExists(name string, client *elastic.Client) bool {
```

states that `CheckBucketExists` expects a `*elastic.Client`.

The lines:

```
m := MockClient{}
m.On("IndexExists", "thisuri").Return(true) 
r := CheckBucketExists("thisuri", m)
```

pass a `MockClient` to the `CheckBucketExists` function.

This is causing a type conflict.

Perhaps you need to import `github.com/olivere/elastic` into your test file and do:

```
m := &elastic.Client{}
```

instead of

```
m := MockClient{}
```

But I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to do.